# Which are the appropriate washing solvents for gas chromatography equipment?

Tags: solvents, chromatography, equipment

I work in a laboratory where gas chromatography is used extensively. We handle terpenes and terpenoids (alcohols, ketones, and acetates derived from terpenes), organic solvents (acetone, acetonitrile, ethyl acetate, hexane, and toluene), acetic acid, and water.

I want to know which are the most appropriate solvents to use for washing the equipment or which criteria should I use to decide among the existing solvents. Now, we are using acetone and ethanol, but sometimes it seems that they do not work for some terpenoids (the syringe sticks and sometimes the equipment crashes). Any suggestions about this?

Comment: What does the manual for you system say?